# Variable modification triggers error

Tags: python

A certain function `operation`, an external service, and *sometimes* fails. I want to try it `N` times before giving up. For this reason I wrote the retry code as a decorator, and now I want to unit-test it.

I made a simple mockup function for the possibly faulty operation: the function fails with exception for `N-1` times, and succeed the `N`-th time.

This is the code:

```
def mock(retry):
    def repl(*xs, **ks):
        if retry == 0:
            return 1
        retry -= 1
        raise error('boom')
    return repl
```

This is how I want to apply it:

```
somemodule.library.operation = mock(N - 1)
somemodule.run() # calls somemodule.library.operation
```

Unexpectedly, by running `mock(N -1)()` I get the following error on the `if retry == 0` line:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'retry' referenced before assignment
```

After trying to understand why, I figured out that the error disappears as soon as I get rid of the `retry -= 1` line.

I'm a bit puzzled by this fact, since in my opinion the `retry` variable should fully belong to the `mock` scope, and not just when it is accessed in read-only. If anything, I should always get the error, not only if I modify it.

Why is this a problem? And what is in your opinion the correct way of doing it?

Note:

- I can see this behavior both with Python2 and Python3
- I also tried to define `global retry` just before the `if retry == 0` conditional

Comment: `retry` is a closure (`repl()` is a new scope, but `retry` comes from the parent scope). Are you using Python 2 or 3? You tagged with both, which isn't all that helpful. In Python 3, mark it `nonlocal`. In Python 2, you can't do what you want directly, [use a mutable closure instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures).

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18002794/3001761? There are plenty of questions on `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, with both python2 and 3. I updated the question.

Comment: @Dacav: I've duplicated your post to one that answers both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks