# Python Variables with Inconsistent Scope

Tags: python

New to python and I found some weird (as a non-python dev) behavior in the way it handles scopes.

I have a code that parses arguments and uses them via argparser.

Shortened basic version of what I am doing:

```
import ...

def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do stuff')
    parser.add_argument('-key', dest='key', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-start_date', dest='start_date', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-end_date', dest='end_date', action='store')
    return parser.parse_args()

args = get_parser()
client_id = args.key
distance_in_meters = 5000

sdate = args.start_date
start_date = datetime(int(sdate[0:4]),int(sdate[4:6]),int(sdate[6:8]),int(sdate[8:10]))
end_date = datetime(datetime.now().year,datetime.now().month,datetime.now().day,datetime.now().hour,datetime.now().minute)
if args.end_date:
    end_date = datetime(int(args.end_date[0:4]),int(args.end_date[4:6]),int(args.end_date[6:8]),int(args.end_date[8:10]))

def search():
    # print example for the sake of stack overflow
    print "Kicking off search."
    print "Client ID:", client_id
    print "Distance in Meters:", distance_in_meters
    print "Start Date:", start_date

    ...

search()
```

This will print everything before erroring out on `print "Start Date:", start_date` which is caused by `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_date' referenced before assignment`

This would normally make sense to me since I didn't set any `global` variables however,

- why was it able to print the other variables?
- why does changing the variable to `sdate` instead of `start_date` work?

I know that it is able to be printed because if I move

```
sdate = args.start_date
start_date = datetime(int(sdate[0:4]),int(sdate[4:6]),int(sdate[6:8]),int(sdate[8:10]))
```

and put it inside `search():` it will print.

Based on this question: "[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)" my code should work fine.

**UPDATE**

I think `start_date`/`end_date` might be reserved variables?

I thought maybe the `start_date` in my `parser()` was somehow the conflicting variable. So I changed `start_date = ...` to `start_date1 = ...` and magically `print "Start Date:", start_date1` seems to work.

However, I decided if that doesn't work then `key` (which is in the parser) should NOT work either. So I changed the code `start_date1 = ...` to `key = ...` and surprisingly `print "Start Date:", key" still works.

So I figured out a solution but I am still confused. I don't see start_date on the list of reserved variables for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start_date` is definitely not a reserved variable in Python.

The issue is almost certainly hidden in the area of code that you've omitted:

```
def search():
    # print example for the sake of stack overflow
    print "Kicking off search."
    print "Client ID:", client_id
    print "Distance in Meters:", distance_in_meters
    print "Start Date:", start_date

    ... #<- This bit
```

You are almost certainly going to have an assignment to `start_date` somewhere in the omitted code.  If you assign a value to a variable name somewhere in a function, you cannot access a global variable of the same name, even before the assignment.  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-in-python) for more details.

For an illustration of this issue, try the following:

```
>>> s = 1
>>> def f():
...     print s
>>> print f()
1

>>> s = 1
>>> def g():
...     print s
...     s = 2
>>> print g()
Traceback (most recent call last):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I see. Interesting how python handles this. Very different from what I am used to. Thanks.