# local variable y referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2. I don't know what is wrong with my code, wrong message is "local variable y referenced before assignment". But variable y is assigned before referenced and there is no problem for variable x. Could you help to figure it out?

```
  def dyn_seq(n):
        C=[0,0,1,1]
        for i in range(4,n+1):
            z=C[i-1]+1
            if i % 2==0: 
                x=C[i/2]+1
            if i % 3==0:
                y=C[i/3]+1
            minu=min(x,y,z)
            C.append(minu)
        return C
```

Comment: I can run it normally. Can you give more information?

Comment: please show your full code and error message

Comment: And maybe your problem is duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a modulo division and your running variable starts at 4. `4 % 2 == 0` and `x` will be defined, while `4 % 3 != 0` and `y` is not defined, but used in the next line.

Comment: Thanks! That is the exactly problem!