# UnboundLocalError error: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in selenium python. I pasted here part of the code from my program (I did not paste all the code because it has 800 lines) with the UnboundLocalError error: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment, the error occurs exactly at i += 1.

```
    global i
    i = 0
    odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb0()

def odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb0():
    if i > ileraz:
        driver.quit
        skonczono()
'''
    try:
        testt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('')
    except Exception:
        odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb1()
    zleskonczono1()
'''
def odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb1():
    i += 1
```

Comment: A "global" declaration must be repeated in each function which should use the global variable instead of a local one.

Comment: `i` is not within the scope of that last function.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-in-python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` keyword tells the function, not the whole module / file, what variables should be considered declared outside the scope of the said function. Try this:

```
def odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb1():
    global i
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

You can use your global variable:

```
def odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb1():
    global i
    i += 1
```

or you pass the i to the function:

```
def odpowiadanieobserwowaniestronfb1( i ):
    return i += 1
```