# "local variable referenced before asignement" but it's a function

Tags: python

I have a code in Jupyter (Python) gives me that warning and doesn't run the code but... well, the "variable" that doesn't run is a function.
In one cell I have something like

```
def rr1(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]
```

And in the next cell I have

```
def function_2(y,z):
    A=np.random.rand(y[0],y[1])
    B=rr1(A[0])
    C=abs(B)**2
    for it in range(z):
    [d,e,f]=[rr1(A[it+1]),rr2(A[it+1]),rr3(A[it+1])]
    if(things.happen()):
    ...
    for blablabla:
        [rr1,rr2,rr3]=[more,things,in_lists]
    return blabla

cosa=function_2([3,5],4)
```

When I try to implement function_2 it gives me the warning local variable rr1 referenced before asignement". Why? What I can do?
Well... all the problem was that after using the function a few times, I called a few variables with the name of the function... Brilliant :face_palm:
Trying to make the "Minimal, Reproducible example" worked. Many thanks.

Comment: Post all your code please in a code block by highlighting it and pressing CTRL-K.

Comment: It's pages long, do I need to post all of it? That's the only thing I changed and it's where it fails...

Comment: @Uli_WH Create a [minimal reproducible exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll do that.

Comment: Just try running the before cell where function is written

Comment: @Amith I'll like to upvote your answer. It was very helpfull.

Comment: Add `global rr1` to the function, since you don't *want* a local variable. While you can read globals by fallback, writing them requires you to tell the compiler that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variable referenced before assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: Not, because rr1 isn't a variable (even if I added then a variable that was called like the function... things happen when recycling code without being careful...)

Answer (score 0):

Run the first cell containing the function rr1 first then the second function where you reference rr1. It can't find the first function probably because you haven't executed it yet.

Comment: Sometimes, when you close jupyter and continue after some time, the variable gets deleted. So, this answer should solve your problem.