# local variable 'name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn python and I created some lines of codes, and in theses lines, I created a system of login. So I created a system of logout too. BUT, when I tried to put the name's variable into another to register it, an error was displayed as :
***UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment***
So I checked this website and it tell me to put the variable in global, and when I tried, another error was displayed as :
***SyntaxError: name 'name' is used prior to global declaration***
Can somebody here help me?

```
def menu():
    menu=input("type 1 to logout and login after : ")
    if menu="1":
    print("")
    print("You're now logout.")
    print("")
    menu=int(menu)
    log_name=name
    log_password=password


    name_inscription_confirm=0
    password_inscription_confirm=0
    print("")
    print("Hello,")
    print("")
    name_inscription=input("What's your name?")

    while name_inscription_confirm==0:
        print("")
        name_inscription=input("What's your name?")

        if name_inscription==log_name:
    
            name_inscription_confirm=1

            password_inscription=input("What's your password?")

            if password_inscription==log_password:
                print("Welcome back '{}'!".format(log_name))

                password_inscription_confirm=1
            else:
                print("")
                print("incorrect password") 
                password_inscription_confirm=0


        else:
            print("incorrect username")
            name_inscription_confirm=0
            continue

        pass

    pass
```

And then:

```
name=input("Choose your name : ")
print("")
password=input("Choose your password : ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variable referenced before assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: Can you post the change made to your code?

Answer (score 0):

In `log_name=name`, it doesn't know that you mean the *global* `name` (which you did assign to), and assumes it is a local one (which hasn't been assigned to).